# where could one download one minute climate archive？

Tags: data-request, weather, time-series

I have been searching for an archive of one minute climate data. I found bad-quality [data from NOAA](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/land-based-station-data/land-based-datasets/automated-surface-observing-system-asos). Some period data is missing.

Data available through [this form](http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/data/) needs a fee of $90 for just one city.

Where else to download one minute climate data?

Comment: I *think* I know what you mean with "1 minute climate data", but it a small explanation in your question could be helpful, so that people don't have to go elsewhere to look it up.

Comment: What do you mean "some period data is missing" from https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/land-based-station-data/land-based-datasets/automated-surface-observing-system-asos ?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that data from bom.gov.au costs $90 per city? I was able to download data from them for free. For example, here's a link to climate data for the SYDNEY (OBSERVATORY HILL) observation site:
http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/averages/tables/cw_066062.shtml

You can filter and sort the table in various ways directly on the webpage, and download it in csv or pdf format.

However since the data is available for individual points, I don't think it meets your "one minute" requirement. It would have to be a raster with one minute (1/60 of a degree) resolution. You could download data for many weather stations and interpolate it in GIS software.

Answer (score 0):

The Measurement and Instrumentation Data Center ([MIDC](https://midcdmz.nrel.gov)) from NREL has 1 minute weather time series for some 30 stations in the US.

One example - [Nevada Power Clark Station](https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/apps/sitehome.pl?site=NPC) and link to [data export](https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/apps/daily.pl?site=NPC&start=20060327&yr=2015&mo=03&dy=03).

You can export individual weather measurements, or "All 1-Min Raw Data" with either ASCII text or ZIP compressed. Choose what you want and click "Submit".

[image]

*([my source](https://sam.nrel.gov/node/69925))*

Answer (score 0):

The [WorldClim](https://www.worldclim.org/data/worldclim21.html) data seems to be what you are looking for. The latest version (released in January 2020) includes climate data for 1970-2000. There are monthly climate data for minimum, mean, & maximum temperature, precipitation, wind speed, and other “bioclimatic” variables. It also includes data that are 10, 5 2.5 or 0.5 Minutes apart.